# Why 404 error unknown permanently in Beego?

Tags: go, model-view-controller, routes, http-status-code-404, beego

I use Beego for my project, but after setting up the project, I only get 404 errors...
My main.go is ok, as well as my router.
Any idea of ​​the problem, I've been looking for several hours, in vain...

main.go

```
import (
    _ "bealinkapi/routers"
    "github.com/beego/beego/v2/client/orm"
    beego "github.com/beego/beego/v2/server/web"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    orm.RegisterDriver("Postgres", orm.DRPostgres)
    orm.DefaultTimeLoc = time.UTC
    o, _ := beego.AppConfig.String("sqlconn")
    err := orm.RegisterDataBase("MyAppName", "postgres", o)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if beego.BConfig.RunMode == "dev" {
        beego.BConfig.WebConfig.DirectoryIndex = true
        beego.BConfig.WebConfig.StaticDir["/swagger"] = "swagger"
    }
    beego.Run()
}
```

router.go

```
// @APIVersion 1.0.0
// @Title beego Test API
// @Description beego has a very cool tools to autogenerate documents for your API
// @Contact astaxie@gmail.com
// @TermsOfServiceUrl http://beego.me/
// @License Apache 2.0
// @LicenseUrl http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
package routers

import (
    "bealinkapi/controllers"

    beego "github.com/beego/beego/v2/server/web"
)

func init() {
    ns := beego.NewNamespace("/v1",
        beego.NSNamespace("/bl_user",
            beego.NSInclude(
                &controllers.BlUserController{},
            ),
        ),
    )
    beego.AddNamespace(ns)
}
```

console:
`2022/04/11 15:04:55.627 [D] [router.go:1272]  |      127.0.0.1| 404 |    265.248µs| nomatch| GET      /v1/bl_user/1`

Comment: Do your controller have the functions for all http methods? (say POST, GET, PUT, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when using the swagger interface to test the api calls, but when I did a postman call it was normal, for some reason the problem was with swagger. Also when I created new namespaces and routers everything worked as expected when testing in postman.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. From Bee V2.0.2 you have to generate the routers using an extra command.

[Bee V2.0.3 release notes](https://github.bns/beego/bee/releases/tag/v2.0.3)

Try this:

```html
bee generate routers
bee run
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the file named **commentsRouter_controller.go**
Seems this file is missing in your project.

commentsRouter_controller.go is generated automatically. If not please check this link for more info https://github.com/beego/beego/issues/2520